# xampp cannot connect to localhost

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I just re installed xampp on my computer. When I did mysql started fine but Apache didn't, so I changed the port it was using 80 I think and changed it to 88. It then all worked fine. I have just started my laptop this morning which is the following morning from the reinstall and when I go to local host it says chrome could not connect to local host, but Apache and mysql started fine. And it worked fine yesterday.
Is it to do with the port change?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `localhost:88`?

Comment: Not sure about the port change but if you use skype there can be a clash. So maybe reinstall xampp and completely quit skype, then start Apache, if this matches your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes you have to enable `work offline` in browsers. You can try 127.0.0.1:88 / localhost:88

Comment: localhost:88 worked thanks a lot for the help